# WSO2 API Manger ApiCtl Request Entity Too Large

Tags: command-line-interface, wso2-api-manager

We are using a WSO2 Api Manager v3.2.0 and want to import an api via corresponding `apictl` command. One of our apis has a `swagger.json` file with a filesize of about 250kb which is not that large for my understanding. When trying to import this api I get an Error 413 - Request Entity too large. Interesting is, that when triggering multiple times it works. Means 1 out of 5 or 6 times it works as expected. The other times it fails with 413. We have no additional proxy in between and are talking natively to the api manager using insecure self-signed certs.

apictl version:

```
Version: 3.2.1
Build Date: 2020-09-29 12:55:11 UTC
```

```
apictl import-api -k -e int --update -f path/to/specs
```

path/to/specs:

```
.
├── api_params.yml
└── Meta-information
    ├── api.json
    └── swagger.json
```

What we tried so far was setting/raising additional configuration values (only maxHttpHeaderSize seems suitable) in `deployment.toml` as follows:

```
[transport.http.properties]
maxHttpHeaderSize = 819200

[transport.https.properties]
maxHttpHeaderSize = 819200
```

Values are getting set correctly in `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`, but still the import fails with code 413 (but randomly works).

Any idea which direction to go or which config variable to set? Is there a caching problem that also may come into play?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error “413 – Request Entity Too Large” indicates that the Nginx server configured to restrict large file size.
Nginx can be set to allow the maximum size of the client request body using the `client_max_body_size` directive. If the size of a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error returned to the client

So in order to increase the client_max_body_size,

1. Edit the conf file of Nginx:

   `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. Add a line in the HTTP section: (Add the expected body size)

   ```
   http {
       client_max_body_size <your_size> ;
   }
   ```
3. Save and restart the Nginx server.

Try the above-mentioned steps and try the same scenario again to verify whether the same issue persists.

Comment: Which nginx?! As already said, we have no additional proxies/balancers/etc in between. We are working with native/integrated httpd.